# PDF files under symfony firewall

Tags: php, symfony, pdf, firewall

How to setup all pdf files in specify folder under the symfony firewall ?

I`ve tried:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/(admin|uploads/umowy|uploads/invoices|*.pdf)/
```

I want to disable open/download any pdf file in /uploads/umowy or /uploads/invoices, User need to be login. 
Any Idea?

Comment: You  should serve your files within a controller

Comment: yes, but if i.e. someone know the link to the file, can open it.

Comment: Sure, in fact you should move your files under var/ or any other dir outside the public/ or the web/ dirs

Comment: yeah, and serve it with abssolute path twig extensions, correct ?

Comment: You can serve your files like this https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#serving-files